# Processing records in order in Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm new to Storm and I'm having problems to figure out how to process records in order.

I have a dataset which contains records with the following fields:

user_id, location_id, time_of_checking

Now, I would like to identify users which have fulfilled the path I specified (for example, users that went from location A to location B to location C).

I'm using Kafka producer and reading this records from a file to simulate live data. Data is sorted by date.

So, to check if my pattern is fulfilled I need to process records in order. The thing is, due to parallelization (bolt replication) I don't get check-ins of user in order. Because of that patterns won't work.

How to overcome this problem? How to process records in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general system support for ordered processing in Storm. Either you use a different system that supports ordered steam processing like Apache Flink (**Disclaimer, I am a committer at Flink**) or you need to take care of it in your bolt code by yourself.

The only support Storm delivers is using Trident. You can put tuples of a certain time period (for example one minute) into a single batch. Thus, you can process all tuples within a minute at once. However, this only works if your use case allows for it because you cannot related tuples from different batches to each other. In your case, this would only be the case, if you know that there are points in time, in which all users have reached their destination (and no other use started a new interaction); ie, you need points in time in which no overlap of any two users occurs. (It seems to me, that your use-case cannot fulfill this requirement).

For non-system, ie, customized user-code based solution, there would be two approaches:

You could for example buffer up tuples and sort on time stamp within a bolt before processing. To make this work properly, you need to inject punctuations/watermarks that ensure that no tuple with larger timestamp than the punctuation comes after a punctuation. If you received a punctuation from each parallel input substream you can safely trigger sorting and processing.

Another way would be to buffer tuples per incoming substream in district buffers (within a substream order is preserved) and merge the tuples from the buffers in order. This has the advantage that sorting is avoided. However, you need to ensure that each operator emits tuples ordered. Furthermore, to avoid blocking (ie, if no input is available for a substream) punctuations might be needed, too. (I implemented this approach. Feel free to use the code or adapt it to your needs: https://github.com/mjsax/aeolus/blob/master/queries/utils/src/main/java/de/hub/cs/dbis/aeolus/utils/TimestampMerger.java)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not happy to hear that, but nevertheless, your answer is very helpful. And I will take a look at your source code, thanks for that, also.

Comment: One more question, if I may, can I expect that the records are processed in order, but only in a distributed manner, so the output is not in-order? That is, if I set the window length to be 10 seconds, can I expect to aggregate all the records produced in that seconds? If I'm producing records from a file (currently), I can expect that in case of one partition KafkaSpout will emit records in order, bolts that get records by "shuffle" from spout will only distribute it's processing, and bolt that has a window of 10 seconds will able to accumulate the records, right?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow... General: for each substream, record are transfered FIFO, ie, if you emit in order, the tuples will be received in order.

Answer (score 0):

Storm supports this use case. For this you just have to ensure that order is maintained throughout your flow in all the involved components. So as first step, in Kafka producer, all the messages for a particular user id should go to the same partition in Kafka. For this you can implement a custom Partitioner in your KafkaProducer. Please refer to the link [here](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/06/04/write-apache-kafka-custom-partitioner/) for implementation details.

Since a partition in Kafka can be read by one and only one kafkaSpout instance in Storm, the messages in that partition come in order in the spout instance. Thereby ensuring that all the messages of the same user id arrive to the same spout.

Now comes the tricky part - to maintain order in bolt, you want to ensure that you use field grouping on bolt based on "user_id" field emitted from the Kafka spout. A provided kafkaSpout does not break the message to emit field, you would have to override the kafkaSpout to read the message and emit a "user_id" field from the spout. One way of doing so is to have an intermediate bolt which reads the message from the Kafkaspout and emits a stream with "user_id" field.

When finally you specify a bolt with field grouping on "user_id", all messages of a particular user_id value would go to the same instance of the bolt, whatever be the degree of parallelism of the bolt.

A sample topology which work for your case could be as follow -

builder.setSpout("KafkaSpout", Kafkaspout);

builder.setBolt("FieldsEmitterBolt", FieldsEmitterBolt).shuffleGrouping("KafkaSpout");

builder.setBolt("CalculatorBolt", CalculatorBolt).fieldsGrouping("FieldsEmitterBolt", new Fields("user_id")); //user_id field emitted by Bolt2

--Beware, there could be case when all the user_id values come to the same CalculatorBolt instance if you have limited number of user_ids. This in turn would decrease the effective 'parallelism'!

Comment: Is FieldsEmitterBolt really needed? You can use fieldsGrouping right from spout, don't you?

Comment: In this particular case, it would be needed. KafkaSpout will not emit "user_id" as a field to be able to group. So the downstream bolt will not be able to group messages by user id. You have two choices, either extend the base KafkaSpout and add the logic to emit "user_id" as a field to be able to add field grouping directly with CalculatorBolt, OR have a field emitter bolt, which reads "user_id" from source tuple, extract "user_id" and emit as a field so that the downstream bolts and add their field grouping on it.